# How can i get Request Referer in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, header, request, referer

```
def total
   puts requeset.referrer
   transactions = UTransaction.all
   render json: amount(transactions)
end
```

i got following error in console

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `requeset' for #<Api::V1::Admin::UTransactionsController:0x007f98d49539d0>)
```

Comment: you have a typo that should be `request` not `requeset`

Comment: `request` is misspelled

Comment: `referrer` is not misspelled.  I take it that in this usage, unlike in, say, HTTP headers, it's not supposed to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right method, `referrer`, but you need to call it on the `request` object.

```
puts requeset.referrer
```

should be

```
puts request.referrer
```

Comment: I found that `request.referrer` (invoked in `create` method) gives me `http://localhost:3000/items` when responding to requests from `http://localhost:3000/items/new`.  What happened to `/new`?

Comment: Impossible to tell without more information. Open a new question and include the server log output?